# Alt Gr makes mouse flash in VNC

Tags: vnc, tigervnc, x11vnc

I have a setup where i run X11VNC on a Debian distribution and connect to it via TigerVNC on a Win10 PC. But whenever I press Alt Gr a ring of black/grey-ish rings starts flashing outwards from the mouse cursor. Like shown in the picture:

[image]
 .

Anyone have an idear why this happens, and how to disable this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was related to X11VNC triggering the ctrl-locate mouse OS function when pressing alt+gr. It dissapered when i disabled the feature, using the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse locate-pointer false
```